# calling a function in another contracts gives me an error

Tags: solidity

I have a problem like this. I am very new to solidity Works. I have created two contracts.

This is how my first contract looks.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TrafficFine{
    struct Officer {
        string firstName ;
        string lastName;
        address account;
    }


    address public manager;
    uint public numberOfOffiers;

    mapping(address=>Officer) public officers;

    modifier restricted(){
        require(msg.sender == manager);      
        _;
    }

    constructor () public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }



    function addOfficer(
        string firstName,
        string lastName,
        address officer) public  restricted{

        require(officer!=officers[officer].account);

        Officer  memory newOfficer = Officer({
            firstName:firstName,
            lastName:lastName,
            account:officer
        });

        officers[officer] = newOfficer;
        numberOfOffiers++;
    }



    function getofficer(address officer) public view returns(address){
        return officers[officer].account;

    }
}
```

This is how my second contract looks like.

```
contract DriverProfile{
    address watch_adrs=0x0971b5d216af52c411c9016bbc63665b4e6f2542;

    struct Driver{
        string lisenceId;
        string firstName ;
        string lastName; 
        address account;
        string vehicle;
        string vehicleType;
        uint totalOffenceAmount;
        uint offenceCount;
        uint pendingPayments;
        mapping(uint=>Fine)  fines;
    }




    TrafficFine trafficfine;
    Driver public driver;

    constructor(string lisenceId,string firstName,string lastName,string vehicle,string vehicleType,address owner) public{
        trafficfine = TrafficFine(watch_adrs);
        trafficfine.addDriver();
        driver = Driver({
            lisenceId:lisenceId,
            lastName:lastName,
            firstName:firstName,
            account:owner,
            vehicle:vehicle,
            vehicleType:vehicleType,
            totalOffenceAmount:0,
            offenceCount:0,
            pendingPayments:0
        });

    }




     function doFine(uint offenceID,string location,address officer) public {
        address officersel=trafficfine.getOfficer(officer);
        require(officer==officersel);
        driver.offenceCount++;
     }

}

    contract TrafficFine{
        function addOfficer(string firstName,string lastName,address officer) public;
        function getOfficer(address officer) public view returns (address);

    }
```

This works very finely without ,

```
address officersel=trafficfine.getOfficer(officer);
require(officer==officersel);
```

these two lines of code but when I put these two line transaction is failed. I try to figure it out what is wrong with this. But I was unable to do that. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first contract lists the method as `getofficer(address officer)`, while your interface lists it as `getOfficer(address officer)`. Since solidity uses the function name and parameter list to calculate the function signature, it is case sensitive.

As the code currently stands, you are calling a non-existent function. Update your two implementations to have the same function name.